# Run native C++ code on codename one

Tags: codenameone

I have an android app where I am running native C++ code using JNI (Java Native Interface). I want to port it to codename one so that it can run on iOS as well. What is the alternative to JNI on codename one that will allow me to run my native C++ code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call C++ from Objective-C we did just that in the ZXing demo for the iOS port see: http://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-demos

For Android you will need to wrap the C++ code using the NDK in order to use it. Chen discussed this a while back in a blog post here: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/integrating-android-3rd-party-libraries-jni.html

The relevant section is this:

> We recently added a 3rd option :aar files. The aar file is a binary format from Google that represents an Android Library project.
>   One of the problem with the Android Library projects was the fact that
>   it required the project sources which made it difficult for 3rd party
>   vendors to publish libraries, so android introduced the aar file which
>   is a binary format that represents a Library project.
>
> To learn  more about arr you can read [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format).
>
> You can link an aar file by placing it under the native/android and
>   the build server will link it to the project.

Notice that for Android you might want to use the new gradle build system which would also make this simpler: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/material-icons-background-music-geofencing-gradle.html

Answer (score 1):

Codenameone has it's native interface that allows adding native codes.

Each platform has it's native code and as far as I know C++ is not in any of them.

I would suggest you translate your code from C++ to Java and Objective-C manually and you can use those code in implementing CN1 native interface.

Read about Native Interface [here](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-interface.html) and also have a look at [native demo](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-demos/tree/master/NativeDemo)

Comment: I am using OpenCV with C++ to run some computer vision algoritihms. So I cant convert it to Java since the OpenCV for Java isnt that powerful.